# How to Allow Audio Autoplay in Phone Browser?

Tags: java, html, audio, autoplay

how can i get permission from mobile user to always allow autoplay audio in my wordpress website ?

`<audio autoplay="1" preload="none" style="width: 50%;" controls controlsList="nodownload" ><source type="audio/mpeg" src="1.mp3?_=1" /></audio>`

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.